# Including Inventory Number in global search

Tags: odbc, netsuite

I actually can't find any option how can i add this Inventory Number entries (subtab on item records) in global search. It would save me a lot of time if this field can be searchable under global netsuite's search which is located in header of every single page.

Is something like this possible? I asked their support and they are navigating me to their support documentation which is not that rich when this question is placed.

Please see screenshot of what i want to include in my global search

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way that I know of to make default fields accessible to the global search but you can make custom fields accessible.

You should be able to make a custom field that stores the value of the Inventory Number. Custom fields have a checkbox of "Global Search". The field must store the value so you will need to make sure that it updates if the Inventory Number ever updates (workflow/suitescript).

#### From NetSuite article 8403 titled "Including Custom Fields in Global Search":

> To index a custom field to be included in global search, a user with
> permission to edit or create custom fields must check the Global
> Search box on the custom field record. By default, the Available for
> Global Search box is not checked for preexisting or new custom fields.
>
> Global search indexing is available for the following data types, when
> the Store Value preference is enabled:
>
> - Currency
> - Decimal Number
> - Email Address
> - Free-Form Text
> - Help
> - Hyperlink
> - Inline HTML
> - Integer Number
> - Percent
> - Phone Number
> - Text Area
>
> You cannot index a custom field for global search if None is
> selected for any Level for Search/Reporting option on the Access
> subtab of the custom field record.